# Creating an Expandable List View in a Fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, fragment, expandablelistview

I cannot get past a problem that comes up because it's in a fragment and not in the MainActivity.  I have rewritten this code several ways and cannot get it to work.  "this" in the listViewAdapter in the FAQFragment is showing an error that doesn't show up if I just write it in MainActivity.
I'm trying to make a FAQ fragment, and ideally have a grandchild with the answer to the question(child) from the topic(parent). I haven't figured out how to do that yet either.  Please help or direct me to a better method of doing this.

***FAQFragment:***

```
package com.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.content.Context
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_f_a_q.*

class FAQFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var listViewAdapter: FAQAdapter
    private lateinit var questionList : List<String>
    private lateinit var answerList : HashMap<String, List<String>>


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        showList()

        listViewAdapter = FAQAdapter(this,questionList, answerList)
        FAQList.setAdapter(listViewAdapter)


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_a_q, container, false)
    }

    private fun showList() {
        questionList = ArrayList()
        answerList = HashMap()

        (questionList as ArrayList<String>).add("Question 1")
        (questionList as ArrayList<String>).add("Question 2")
        (questionList as ArrayList<String>).add("Question 3")
        (questionList as ArrayList<String>).add("Question 4")
        (questionList as ArrayList<String>).add("Question 5")

        val answer1: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        answer1.add("Answer 1")
        answer1.add("Answer 2")
        answer1.add("Answer 3")

        val answer2: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        answer2.add("Answer 1")
        answer2.add("Answer 2")
        answer2.add("Answer 3")

        val answer3: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        answer3.add("Answer 1")
        answer3.add("Answer 2")
        answer3.add("Answer 3")

        val answer4: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        answer4.add("Answer 1")
        answer4.add("Answer 2")
        answer4.add("Answer 3")

        val answer5: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        answer5.add("Answer 1")
        answer5.add("Answer 2")
        answer5.add("Answer 3")

        answerList[questionList[0]] = answer1
        answerList[questionList[1]] = answer2
        answerList[questionList[2]] = answer3
        answerList[questionList[3]] = answer4
        answerList[questionList[4]] = answer5

    }


}
```

***FAQAdapter:***

```
package com.app

import android.content.Context
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*

class FAQAdapter internal constructor(private val context: Context, private val questionList: List<String>, private val answerList: HashMap<String, List<String>>): BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
        return questionList.size
    }

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
        return this.answerList[this.questionList[groupPosition]]!!.size
    }

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any {
        return questionList[groupPosition]
    }

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
        return this.answerList[this.questionList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition]
    }

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
        return groupPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
        return childPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun getGroupView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        isExpanded: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View {

        var convertView = convertView
        val questionTitle = getGroup(groupPosition) as String
        if(convertView == null){
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_questions, null)
        }

        val questionTv = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_list_tv)
        questionTv.setText(questionTitle)

        return convertView

    }

    override fun getChildView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        childPosition: Int,
        isLastChild: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View {

        var convertView = convertView
        val answerTitle = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String
        if(convertView == null){
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_answers, null)
        }

        val answerTv = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_list_tv)
        answerTv.setText(answerTitle)

        return convertView
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `requireContext()` instead of `this`.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.